# Which one is better for OAuth process? SFSafariViewController? WKWebview?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm using `SFSfariViewController` for `OAuth` process. Using this I'm getting a quite well response. Whenever redirecting happens, it's opening my app. But when the request fails, I'm not able to show any alert to the user to indicate authentication failed. At this point, I can't customize `SFSafariViewController` as it won't allow customizations. So that's why I want to move to `WKWebview` which allows customization.

Even though `WKWebView` allows customization, From this [article](https://www.gluu.org/blog/webviews-are-bad-use-appauth/) it's saying that Web views are not good to use for OAuth process and using SFSafariViewController is the best in this situation.

**My Question:**

Which one has to use `WKWebview`? or `SFSafariViewController`?
If so, Why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`SFSafariViewController`.

It's better for:

- user security

  - credentials protected from app developer
- ease of use for users

  - use of stored Safari credentials
  - Safari shared cookies/authentication maintain login across apps

I think it's fairly safe to say Apple will start enforcing the use of `SFSafariViewController` for the OAuth flow for the sake of customer privacy and security.